# How can i back through action button without required input Field error?

Tags: apex, dynamic-visualforce

This is my first question. I have some doubts about one trouble. I saw that it could be there  a duplicate question, but i'll try anyways.

My vf page code is below:

```
<apex:form >
   <apex:pageblock >
    <apex:pageBlockButtons >
    <apex:commandButton value="Cancelar" action="{!cancelar}" />
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
   <apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:repeat value="{!mapaCantProductos}" rendered="{!IF(tempListaInnerProd.size != 0,true,false)}" var="ipId">
     <apex:repeat value="{!mapaCantProductos[ipId]}" var="oli">
        <apex:inputField value="{!oli.UnitPrice}" label=""/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!oli.serviceDate}" label="" required="true" />
      </apex:repeat>
     </apex:repeat>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
   </apex:pageblock>
  </apex:form>
```

And the controller code is:

```
 public PageReference cancelar(){
    PageReference pf = new PageReference('/'+this.opp.Id);
    pf.setRedirect(true);
    return pf;
 }
```

Then when i try to click on it, an inputField required error is displayed: "Must write a value" or something like that. I could read some about apex:ActionRegion tags to split up the form into various groups of fields with their associated actions.

My inputFields within apex:form and apex:pageBlock are below:

```
 <apex:inputField value="{!oli.serviceDate}" label="" required="true" />
```

Thanks in advance, any help to handle this situacion will be helpful.

Comment: Can you add more code; that will be helpful.

Comment: Added the entire form. the problem is when i do click on "Cancelar" button only i have to back to other page. But the actual page it doesn't let me "go back" (pageReference) because it says me that i must to enter a value although the row is empty.

Comment: r u submitting form without entering any value in 'oli.serviceDate'?

Comment: Yep! I'm submitting, but the target of that Submit is only go to the "opportunity" page, meaning go to the previous page

Comment: set default value to the field 'serviceDate'. It will work.

Answer (score 1):

set default value to the field 'serviceDate'.

OR

set immediate="true"

Comment: immediate="true" should be the way to go here, setting this means it will bypass all validations and carry out the postback action.